# How to open excel native taskbar/contextual menu from excel add-in taskpane?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, add-in, excel-addins

I am developing an Excel add-in using Office JS API. Now, I want to open the native Excel taskbar/contextual menu from the add-in task pane.

Could you please guide me on how to implement this functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such interface publicly available, and it is not planned in the near future.

If we receive more requests in future, we will consider putting it into our backlog.

This [community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) is where we collect requests from developers. Please upvote or request your desired feature there.